# Django, knockout and requirejs

Tags: django, knockout.js, requirejs

Can't figure out how Django, knockout and requirejs vibe with each other. Everything I try I get 'ReferenceError: ko is not defined', or some similar message. My current code looks something like this:

**base.html:**

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SiteConfig = { baseStaticUrl: "{{ STATIC_URL }}" };
    require(['{{ STATIC_URL }}js/require_config.js'], function (require_config) {
        {% block require_javascript %}
        {% endblock require_javascript %}
    });
</script>
```

**require_config.js:**

```
require.config({
    "baseUrl": SiteConfig.baseStaticUrl,
    "paths": {
        'jquery': SiteConfig.baseStaticUrl + 'js/jquery-1.11.0.min',
        'knockout': SiteConfig.baseStaticUrl + 'js/knockout-3.3.0',
        'bootstrap': SiteConfig.baseStaticUrl + 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min',
        'underscore': SiteConfig.baseStaticUrl + 'js/underscore-1.8.3.min'
    },
    "shim": {
        'jquery': {
            'exports': '$'
        },
        'knockout': {
            'exports': 'ko'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            'deps': ['jquery']
        },
        'underscore': {
            'deps': ['jquery'],
            'exports': '_'
        }
    }
});

require(
    ['jquery', 'knockout', 'bootstrap', 'underscore']
);
```

**page.html:**

```
{% block require_javascript %}

    require.config({
        "paths": {
            'flot': '{{STATIC_URL}}flot/jquery.flot.min',
            'multiselect': '{{STATIC_URL}}js/bootstrap-multiselect'
            'mything': '{{STATIC_URL}}mything/js/api',
            'page': '{{STATIC_URL}}patientplans/js/page'
        },
        "shim": {
            'page': {
                'deps': ['flot', 'multiselect', 'mything']
            }
        }
    });

    require(['flot', 'multiselect', 'mything', 'page']);

{% endblock require_javascript %}
```

**page.js:**

```
// Some knockout stuff here

...

$(document).ready(function(){

    require(['knockout', 'jquery', 'js/MyViewModel'], function(ko, $, MyViewModel) {
        ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
    });
});
```

**MyViewModel.js:**

```
define(['knockout', 'jquery'], function(ko, $) {
    return function MyViewModel(){
        var self = this;

        ...

    }
});
```

Now, my thought was that knockout would be accessible via a global variable `ko`, but that doesn't appear in `window` no matter what I try.

A shove in the right direction would be great.

Comment: `ko` isn't going to be a global, it's passed as a parameter to the anonymous function your code is in. Don't look for it to be owned by `window`.

Comment: @Roy J - Hmm, that's strange. I'm trying to add requirejs to an existing project that uses knockout. If I load everything with basic `<script>` tags, I get a `ko` object in `window`. This is how the knockout functionality for the project currently works. Am I missing the idea of how requirejs works maybe?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what you are missing. A major benefit of requirejs is decluttering the global space. Look at the syntax of your viewmodel code. See how ko is a parameter to the function? That's your ko.